How to select Wikipeda element when hovering over it in Chrome Dev Tools?
Even though there are similar questions I have tried many of the solutions and they dont work.
I'm trying to inspect the element when hoovering over the year 1896 in a Wikipedia table. I have tried the following solutions but the popup always closes:

Undock Dev Tools and tab to it after the popup is open, but it still closes.
Forcing the element state to :hover but it does not do anything.

The website in question is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_medal
And this is the popup:


You can press ctrl + shift + c in Chrome and click anchor 1896 to select the element, this should open devtools on the selected element
enter image description here
For the popup element, this is probably not the best solution, but you can Alt + Tab to the devtools window and navigate with Tab and/or arrows without letting your mouse stop hovering over the element

This is what I tried, I tried undocking Devtools window and tabbing to it, but it still disappears.

This is strange, as you can see in the image above I even selected the popup element, maybe it's some Chrome extension that's causing your problem?
